# How Can I Stop a SAS Data Step from Opening a Command Prompt

Tags: sas, command-prompt, datastep

I've successfully executed a call to Python code in my SAS interface, thanks to you lovely folks in the land of Stackoverflow.com. My next question is this: When my data step calls the code, I get a command window that opens up, but nothing appears in it. This seems to be something related to the execution of the Python code, which is fine, but I'd rather not have it pop up. If the user closes out of the window, it breaks the execution of the called Python program.

I'm not sure what to try here, as I'm not certain if the Data step has a way to do this. Is there some option that I might have overlooked?

```
%let _loc = fancypath\Python Code.py;
filename temp pipe "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe ""&_loc""";

data _null_;
infile temp;
input;
put _infile_;
run;
```

[image: Command Window Image]

Ideally, I'd like to have the command window NOT appear. If you folks know of a way to suppress this window's appearance, please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: try noxwait noxsync options.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Instead of a pipe, use an X command statement so you can use the following options:

You're looking for the XMIN, XWAIT, XSYNC or NOXMIN, NOXWAIT, NOXSYNC options.

> **XMIN** 
>   Specifies to open the application specified in the X command in
>   a minimized state or in the default active state.
>
> **XSYNC** Controls whether an X command or statement executes
>   synchronously or asynchronously. That is, control is not returned to
>   SAS until the command has completed. You cannot return to your SAS
>   session until the process spawned by the X command or statement is
>   closed. XSYNC is the default.
>
> **XWAIT** Specifies whether you have to type EXIT at the DOS prompt before
>   the DOS shell closes.

[Documentation references is here.](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=hostwin&docsetTarget=n0xwt90ik8vxdrn13708w6n3nm4o.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=zh-TW)

Comment: xmin, xsync and xwait are for the x command and don't affect pipes or systask

Comment: Changed answer to include, change to X statement instead of Pipe format.

Comment: Maybe he actualy use the output

Comment: you can use the console=min option , which will minimise the command prompt